# Spring boot login 302

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, http-status-code-302

Why i Cannot login I got always returned status 302 after form submission. Please help me to get rid of this. I need to successfully log in to the service. Help is really appreciated!:)

I have class WebSecurityConfiguration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Qualifier("userDetailsServiceImpl")
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceImpl;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsServiceImpl).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        //force to use https!
        http.requiresChannel()
                .requestMatchers(r -> r.getHeader("X-Forwarded-Proto") != null)
                .requiresSecure();

        //http.csrf().disable();

        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/register").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .successHandler(new RefererRedirectionAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
                .loginPage("/user-login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }


    /*@Bean
    public AuthenticationManager customAuthenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return authenticationManager();
    }*/
    @Bean(name = BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return authenticationManager();
    }
}
```

Then in the controller i have GET request method

```
@RequestMapping(value="/user-login", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String login(Model model, String error, String logout) {
    model.addAttribute("login", new Users());
    if (error != null)
        model.addAttribute("error", "Your username and password are invalid.");

    if (logout != null)
        model.addAttribute("message", "You have been logged out successfully.");

    return "user-login";
}
```

And then i have user-login.html

```
<form th:action="@{/login}" th:object="${login}" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="POST">
        <p th:text="${message}">Test</p>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Username:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Enter name" name="username" th:field="*{username}"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Password:</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Enter password" name="password" th:field="*{password}" />
        </div>
        <p th:text="${error}">Test</p>
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">LOGIN</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
        <p th:text="${error}">Test</p>
    </form>
```

Comment: Have you looked at what a [302 status means](https://httpstatuses.com/302)?

Comment: Mind marking my answer as correct? I saw you posted it worked for you, but the comment is now gone?

Answer (score 1):

Likely your CSRF protection is blocking you. Instead of this:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
```

Try this (note the th: prefix)

```
 <input type="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}" />
```

Also:

Make sure this is what you want: RefererRedirectionAuthenticationSuccessHandler . It sounds to me like you "want" to redirect after successful login.